# Hide sequential values in VBA

Tags: arrays, string, vba, sequential

can you suggest me a routine - algorithm in VBA that can take the following String as an input: 
"A14, A22, A23, A24, A25, A33" 
and turn it to this:
"A14, A22 - A25, A33" 
?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @omegastripes

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strText, strRes, strTail, i
    Dim comma     As String: comma = ", "
    Dim dash      As String: dash = "-"
    Dim delimiter As String
    Dim counter   As Integer

    strText = "A14, A22, A23, A24, A25, A26, A33, A34"
    strRes = ""
    strTail = ""
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z])(\d+)"
        With .Execute(strText)
            strRes = .Item(0).Value
            For i = 1 To .Count - 1
                If (.Item(i).SubMatches(0) = .Item(i - 1).SubMatches(0)) And (.Item(i).SubMatches(1) - .Item(i - 1).SubMatches(1) = 1) Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                    If counter > 1 Then
                        delimiter = dash
                    Else
                        delimiter = comma
                    End If
                    strTail = delimiter & .Item(i).SubMatches(0) & .Item(i).SubMatches(1)
                Else
                    Debug.Print "strRes: " & strRes & ", " & "strTail: " & strTail & ", " & .Item(i).SubMatches(1)
                    strRes = strRes & strTail & ", " & .Item(i).SubMatches(0) & .Item(i).SubMatches(1)
                    strTail = ""
                    counter = 0
                End If
            Next
            strRes = strRes & strTail
        End With
    End With

    MsgBox strText & vbCrLf & strRes

End Sub
```

Comment: You might try regex and loop matches, comparing each one with previous to skip adjacent elements within intervals.

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
Function HideValues(inputStrng As String) As String
    Dim outputStrng As String, iniLetter As String, endLetter As String
    Dim vals As Variant, val As Variant
    Dim iVal As Long, iniVal As Long, endVal As Long, diffVal As Long

    vals = Split(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(inputStrng, " ", ""), ",")
    iVal = 0
    Do While iVal < UBound(vals)
        iniVal = getValNumber(vals(iVal), iniLetter)
        endVal = getValNumber(vals(iVal + 1), endLetter)
        If iniLetter = endLetter Then
            diffVal = 1
            Do While endVal = iniVal + diffVal And iVal < UBound(vals) - 1
                diffVal = diffVal + 1
                iVal = iVal + 1
                endVal = getValNumber(vals(iVal + 1), endLetter)
            Loop
            If diffVal > 1 Then
                If iVal = UBound(vals) - 1 Then If endVal = iniVal + diffVal Then iVal = iVal + 1: diffVal = diffVal + 1
                outputStrng = outputStrng & vals(iVal - diffVal + 1) & " - " & vals(iVal) & ","
            Else
                outputStrng = outputStrng & vals(iVal) & ","
            End If
        Else
            outputStrng = outputStrng & vals(iVal) & ","
        End If
        iVal = iVal + 1
    Loop
    If iVal = UBound(vals) Then outputStrng = outputStrng & vals(iVal) & ","
    HideValues = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Left(outputStrng, Len(outputStrng) - 1), ",", ", ")
End Function


Function getValNumber(val As Variant, letter As String) As Long
    Dim strng As String
    Dim i As Long

    strng = CStr(val)
    For i = 1 To Len(strng)
         If Mid(strng, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then Exit For
    Next i
    letter = Left(strng, i - 1)
    getValNumber = CLng(Right(strng, Len(strng) - i + 1))
End Function
```

I tested it with the following:

```
Sub main()
    Dim inputStrng As String

    inputStrng = "A21, B22, C23, D24, E25, F26"
    MsgBox inputStrng & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "becomes" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & HideValues(inputStrng)

    inputStrng = "A21, A22, A23, A24, A25, A26"
    MsgBox inputStrng & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "becomes" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & HideValues(inputStrng)

    inputStrng = "A21, A22, A23, A24, A25, A33" '
    MsgBox inputStrng & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "becomes" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & HideValues(inputStrng)

    inputStrng = "A14, A22, A23, A24, A25, A33"
    MsgBox inputStrng & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "becomes" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & HideValues(inputStrng)

    inputStrng = "A14, A22, A23, A24, A25, A26"
    MsgBox inputStrng & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "becomes" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & HideValues(inputStrng)
End Sub
```

Comment: @michalis: did you get through it?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. If I fullfilled your question please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing how you can hide sequential values with regex:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strText, strRes, strTail, i

    strText = "A14, A22, A23, A24, A25, A33"
    strRes = ""
    strTail = ""
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z])(\d+)"
        With .Execute(strText)
            strRes = .Item(0).Value
            For i = 1 To .Count - 1
                If (.Item(i).SubMatches(0) = .Item(i - 1).SubMatches(0)) And (.Item(i).SubMatches(1) - .Item(i - 1).SubMatches(1) = 1) Then
                    strTail = "-" & .Item(i).SubMatches(0) & .Item(i).SubMatches(1)
                Else
                    strRes = strRes & strTail & ", " & .Item(i).SubMatches(0) & .Item(i).SubMatches(1)
                    strTail = ""
                End If
            Next
            strRes = strRes & strTail
        End With
    End With

    MsgBox strText & vbCrLf & strRes

End Sub
```

And the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Sorry, that I am late. And thank you for your response! 
I made a small change for the case that we have only two sequential values (e.g. A33, A34 we do not want to become A33-A44). I posted my small change.

Comment: @michalis expected that you notice that detail)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly you can do it like this.

```
Sub Way()
Dim str1 As String
Dim cet As variant
Dim str2 As String

str1 =  "A14, A22, A23, A24, A25, A33"
cet = split(str1, ",")

if len(join(cet)) > 2 then
    str2 = cet(0) & "," & cet(1) & "-" & cet(Ubound(cet)-1) & "," & cet(ubound(cet))
End if

debug.Print str2
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your immediate response, but I would like to do this wherever there are more than two sequential values. This works perfectly, but only for this specific example.